# Passing a variable to a Vue component from the parent page that called it

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple table that displays all of my data:

**main file.php**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="all-jobs">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>{{ __('Job Name') }}</th>
            <th>{{ __('Job Description') }}</th>
            <th>{{ __('Job Status') }}</th>
            <th>{{ __('Job Applications') }}</th>
            <th>{{ __('Manage') }}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="non_searchable"></td>
            <td class="non_searchable"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<div id="app">
    <div id="editJob" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <edit-job id=""></edit-job>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I have a edit button that I am trying to open an edit modal for that specific row:

```
<a href='' data-id='{$job->id}' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editJob'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></a>";
```

The href is is location in one of the  of my data table, I am trying to pass that to my .vue file so I can use it for my get and post requests:

**myfile.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
       <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Job</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" @submit.prevent="signIn" @keydown="errors.clear($event.target.name)">
                <!-- Removed code, it's just inputs !-->
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd" v-on:click="addJob">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default
    {
        props: ['id'],
        data: function () 
        {
            return {
                countries: [],
                name: '',
                summary: '',
                salarytype: '',
                salaryfrom: '',
                salaryto: '',
                location: '',
                contactemail: '',
                contactphone: '',
                errors: new Errors()
            }
        },

        methods: 
        {
            addJob: function()
            {
                axios.post('/jobs/edit', this.$data)
                .then(response => {
                    if(response.data.status === true){
                        $('#editJob').modal('hide');
                        getJobTable();
                    }
                    else{
                        formError = response.data.message;
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => this.errors.record(error.data))
            }
        },

        mounted: function()
        {
            console.log($(this).data('id'));
            axios.get('/jobs/my-job/')
                .then(response => {
                    this.name = response.data.name
                    this.summary = response.data.summary
                    this.salarytype = response.data.salary_type
                    this.salaryfrom = response.data.salary_from
                    this.salaryto = response.data.salary_to
                    this.location = response.data.location
                    this.contactemail = response.data.contact
                    this.contactphone = response.data.phone
                })

            axios.get('/countries')
                .then(response => {
                    this.countries = response.data;
                })
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I past my href id to my  to use for my request? Thanks

MY structure:

Created-jobs.blade.php

https://pastebin.com/TPBnC1qP

Edit-Job.vue

https://pastebin.com/30UWR5Nn

app.js

https://pastebin.com/1yxZWvVC

The table just populates the data, and adds the dropdown like so:

```
<ul class='icons-list'>
    <li class='dropdown'>
        <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-expanded='false'>
            <i class='icon-menu9'></i>
        </a>

        <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
            <li>
                <a data-id='{$job->id}' onclick='getID({$job->id})' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editJob'>
                    <i class='icon-file-pdf'></i> Edit Job
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href='javascript:void();' data-id='{$job->id}' onclick='deleteJob({$job->id})'>
                    <i class='icon-cross'></i> Delete Job
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please look at the documenation [vueDoc Props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props)

or if you want to have the code all in the parent you can use <slots> [vueDoc Slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Named-Slots)

Comment: I've looked at the docs for props but couldn't see anything to with passing an id from the href to the prop :(

Comment: Just use a slot in the component tag like in this example https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html you can define everything in the parent template but the slot will be rendered in the component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't give a lot of information about the structure of your application, but it looks like you are using at least one single file component to display the data inside your modal which is being entirely displayed via Bootstrap. It also looks like the table with the `id` values you want to pass to Vue is outside of the Vue itself.

That being the case, the way you can pass the data you want to the single file component is to capture the Vue in a variable and then set the `id` whenever the link in your table is clicked.

Let's suppose your `main.js` or `app.js` looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import EditJob from './EditJob.vue'

Vue.component('edit-job', EditJob)

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:{
   id: null 
  }
})

// Add a click handler for the links with the `data-id` property.
// This is using jQuery (because you are using Bootstrap) but you
// can do this any way you want.
$("[data-id]").on("click", function(){
  // Set the Vue's data to the data-id property in the link.
  app.id = this.dataset.id
})
```

Notice how the code captures the result of `new Vue(...)` in the variable `app`. Then I've added the data property, `id` to the Vue and a click handler for all of your links that sets `app.id` to `this.dataset.id` whenever a link is clicked. In this way, every time a link is clicked, the data property in the Vue will be set to the `id` of the clicked link.

Then, all you need to do is bind the id property to your component.

```
<edit-job :id="id"></edit-job>
```

and your `EditJob` component will always get the updated `id`.

Here is a [working example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Ko4r20TELHXYTj24kGK).

**Edit**

In the code you added to your example, you are defining all of your jQuery script in `Created-jobs.blade.php`. That being the case, the function you wrote, `getID` doesn't have access to the `app` variable you defined in your webpack bundle because of  normal javascript scoping rules. To make `app` accessible to your jQuery code, add it to the `window`.

```
window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        id: null
    }
});
```

Secondly, though you defined the `getID` function, *nothing* calls it. It needs to be called when the links are clicked. Add this somewhere to your jQuery code in `Created-jobs.blade.php` (ideally in a document `ready` function).

```
$("[data-id]").on("click", getID)
```

Comment: I couldn't seem to get it to work, when I loaded the modal the id was still blank . I have updated my OP with the files so you have an idea of the structure. Thanks

Comment: @randommman Added explanation for why your version isn't working and how to fix it.